# how to turn off debug transaction logging in datahike?

Tags: clojure, datalog

- on every transaction datahike logs whole transaction

```
2022-05-24T15:25:00.999Z BB-8 DEBUG [datahike.connector:142] - Using config  {:keep-history? true, :index :datahike.index/hitchhiker-tree, :store {:path "/home/user/.Fennec/Deep-Thought", :backend :file}, :name "main", :attribute-refs? false, :schema-flexibility :write, :index-config {:index-b-factor 17, :index-log-size 283, :index-data-node-size 300}, :cache-size 100000}
2022-05-24T15:25:01.016Z BB-8 DEBUG [datahike.connector:82] - Transacting with arguments:  {:tx-data [#:db{:cardinality :db.cardinality/one, :ident :id, :unique :db.unique/identity, :valueType :db.type/uuid} #:db{:ident :name, :valueType :db.type/string, :cardinality :db.cardinality/one}]}
2022-05-24T15:25:01.073Z BB-8 DEBUG [datahike.connector:82] - Transacting with arguments:  {:tx-data [{:id #uuid "3e7c14ce-5f00-4ac2-9822-68f7d5a60952", :name "Deep-Thought"} {:id #uuid "f82dc4f3-59c1-492a-8578-6f01986cc4c2", :name "Wichita"} {:id #uuid "5358b384-3568-47f9-9a40-a9a306d75b12", :name "Little-Rock"}]}
```

- docs suggest - but it does not have effect

```clj
(taoensso.timbre/merge-config! {:level })
```

- using

```clj
io.replikativ/datahike {:mvn/version "0.5.1504"}
```

how to turn off debug logging?

Answer (score 1):

- timbre has api for this

```clj
(taoensso.timbre/merge-config! {:min-level :warn})
```

WRONG

- turns out datahike uses (log/debug ) directly https://github.com/replikativ/datahike/blob/75af15468fbe36d0398175c3a66e62bd38683e28/src/datahike/connector.cljc#L142
- solution - unpleasant but effective

```clj
(alter-var-root #'taoensso.timbre/debug (constantly (constantly nil)))
```